# GKE mismatch limit of Kubernetes pods per node from official documentation

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am sizing a small kubernetes cluster in Google Cloud Platform, my reference is the following documentation :
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/flexible-pod-cidr#overview

So I have

- 3 nodes
- /24 for pods
- /25 for services
- 16 pods per node set in the cluster creation

When I deploy the cluster and spin up a nginx replicas of PODs I can only reach maximum to 30 while I would expect to reach 48 PODs.

According to Google documentation I should have a /27 (that I can see assigned on each node) and a range of nodes between 9-16.
Now while an average of 10 nodes is fair considering the 9-16 range, I don't understand why it doesn't scale up above that number.

Here is the code for your review, I wasn't able to see if there is any other limitation:

```
gcloud compute networks subnets create $SERVICE_PROJECT1_SUB_K8S_NODES \
--network $SHAREDVPC --region $REGION \
--range 10.222.5.32/28 --secondary-range \
$SERVICE_PROJECT1_SUB_K8S_PODS=10.222.6.0/24, \
$SERVICE_PROJECT1_SUB_K8S_SERVICES=10.222.5.128/25 \
--enable-private-ip-google-access
```

```
gcloud beta container clusters create service1-k8s-cluster \
--zone $REGION \
--network projects/$HOST_PROJECT_ID/global/networks/$SHAREDVPC \
--subnetwork projects/$HOST_PROJECT_ID/regions/$REGION/subnetworks/$SERVICE_PROJECT1_SUB_K8S_NODES \
--cluster-secondary-range-name $SERVICE_PROJECT1_SUB_K8S_PODS \
--services-secondary-range-name $SERVICE_PROJECT1_SUB_K8S_SERVICES \
--enable-master-authorized-networks \
--master-authorized-networks 10.222.1.0/24 \
--enable-ip-alias \
--enable-private-nodes \
--enable-private-endpoint \
--master-ipv4-cidr $SERVICE_PROJECT1_SUB_K8S_MASTER \
--no-enable-basic-auth \
--no-issue-client-certificate \
--enable-master-global-access \
--num-nodes 1 \
--default-max-pods-per-node 16 \
--max-pods-per-node 16 \
--machine-type n1-standard-2
```

Error I see in a POD

```
Events:
  Type     Reason             Age                    From                Message
  ----     ------             ----                   ----                -------
  Normal   NotTriggerScaleUp  4m53s (x151 over 29m)  cluster-autoscaler  pod didn't trigger scale-up (it wouldn't fit if a new node is added):
  Warning  FailedScheduling   8s (x22 over 29m)      default-scheduler   0/3 nodes are available: 3 Insufficient pods.
```

Comment: What do you get when you do `kubectl get no -oyaml | grep pods`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will never reach that 48 threshold, there are some IPs that are used for daemon sets that will prevent you from reaching the high threshold you set for yourself for example in my cluster I have the following

```
 kube-system                fluentd-gcp-v3.1.1-grkv8                                          100m (1%)     1 (12%)     200Mi (0%)       500Mi (1%)     10d
  kube-system                kube-proxy-gke-eng-e2e-main-gke-e2e-n1-highmem-8-501281f5-9ck0    100m (1%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         3d19h
  kube-system                network-metering-agent-ck74l                                      0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         10d
  kube-system                prometheus-to-sd-qqsn6                                            1m (0%)       3m (0%)     20Mi (0%)        37Mi (0%)      10d
  monitor                    prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter-8229c                         0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         11d
  neuvector                  neuvector-enforcer-pod-p79j5                                      100m (1%)     2 (25%)     128Mi (0%)       1Gi (2%)       11d
```

This is for every node the daemon sets deploys these pods on every node, efectively reducing by 6 the amount of IPs available to my application pods.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't find this anywhere easily but I think this makes sense. Do you know where I can find the specs of how many internal services are consumed? just to make a fair assessment of subnets to allocate

Comment: hmmm not really, most of this I get from experience and testing, the default ones I know about are
- Fluentd
- Kube-Proxy
- network-metering-agent
- Prometheus-to-SD. 

If you use prometheus you have to take those into consideration, also different versions of kubernetes have different daemonsets, also take into consideration the pods that kube-system has like: event-exporter, kube-dns (2) , stackdriver pods etc.